# How to use !ImportValue to get the resource arn using AWS SAM template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have a base template, output section is like this:

```
Outputs:
  layerName:
    Value: !Ref Psycopg2LayerLambdaLayer
```

How to get the arn of `Psycopg2LayerLambdaLayer` using the output from the base template in my new template? is this correct?

```
Layers: !ImportValue layerName.arn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an Output value as an Import in a different template, you must export it first. In your example, it might look like the following:

```
Outputs:
  layerArn:
    Value: !GetAtt Psycopg2LayerLambdaLayer.arn
    Export:
      Name: psycopg2LayerArn
```

After deploying this, you can import the value in another stack with `!ImportValue psycopg2LayerArn`.

Note that an export has to have a unique name per account and region, therefore it is a good idea to prefix it with the stack/resource name. Also note that you can’t export objects, only scalar values such as strings.

Read more at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Comment: @Ixg My deployement method was previously using serverless framework.for the same base template using ${cf:basestackname.layerArn} I can easily refer with out using export name. So I was thinking if similar can be done using the output key using SAM or not